# Prove that sum/multiplication of cardinals equals to max of cardinals

Tags: cardinals

Let A,B be infinite sets.

Denote |A|,|B| as the cardinality of A,B.

I am struggling to prove that
|A|+|B| = |A|*|B| = max(|A|,|B|)

Comment: What do you already know about cardinal arithmetic?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I know the basics, but for some reason I struggle with this specific question.

Comment: http://karagila.org/2015/how-to-solve-your-problems/